# Lazy loading external images

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

Google Pagespeed Insights says that I should delay Offscreen Images. I have installed Lazy Load by WP Rocket (https://wordpress.org/plugins/rocket-lazy-load/) but Google still finds that not all images are lazy loaded. The images are some external images from Google and Instagram. How do I lazy load all images?

Analyze: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=da&url=https%3A%2F%2Fforfulgtekristne.dk%2F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below js script to apply lazy loads for all images.

https://apoorv.pro/lozad.js/

Comment: Thanks for that. As far as I see, it is needed to change some HTML markup for the script to work. I want a solution that fits for all images and not only for images with specific markup or class.

Comment: You can use this for all the images tag, it's not for only specific images of class and id.

Comment: Sorry, I can't get it to work for my site. Google Pagespeed still says it is not lazyloaded.